# Есть ли места где можно поучится?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Добрый день. Интересует такая идея, вот я учусь на веб-программиста, есть ли места, где можно попрактиковаться в разработке? Например, человек делает сайт, и ему нужен напарник, хоть не опытный но хоть чем-то помогал, ну и вместе там делали. выгода то что хоть какая-то помощь и мне выгода, научусь может быть или хоть старое не забуду). Соответственно работать буду за знания). реально ли это? или это мечты? знания.... ну PHP,JavaScript,JQuery на уровне: "основы знаю и базовый уровень. То чего не знаю, буду всеми силами стараться узнать", я принял данные в форме html и через JS с JQuery отправил асинхронный запрос PHP тот обрабатывает их и отсылает обратно без перезагрузки страницы. Спасибо!
И ещё, на фрилансере, там в проектах, в которых бесплатно, такие требования... что наверное и за деньги ещё подумать нужно).

Comment: вероятнее всего можно.

Пишите: helenalevina@gmail.com

Comment: И жили они долго и счастливо...

Comment: Это сарказм? все написанное мною - сказка? )

Comment: ну знаете, смех смехом, а подобный опыт уже был, и не раз. В большинстве случаев он был действительно взаимовыгоден.

Answer (score 0):

Да это вполне реально. Есть несколько способов начать. Первый это разослать такое предложение компаниям рядом с вами. Многие охотно поделятся знаниями с человеком, кто не требует достойной оплаты за труд(это может вызывать сомнения у новичка, но поверьте это так). Как вариант, на пол ставки, совмещая с вузом. Чтобы хорошо программировать, нужно просто... программировать. То есть, без практики теория даётся очень плохо, и можно начать с бирж фриланса, брать самые дешёвые задания. Также альтернативным вариантом может быть разработка своего проекта, придумайте проект, лишь бы был лично вам интересным(может быть сайт о том что вам интересно) и начните делать, в процессе будет легче найти себе единомышленников. Также будут возникать проблемы, которые можно будет решить задав вопрос здесь.